# How can we make substitution variables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, substitution

I want to prompt the user to input the 'product_id' through this query in MySQL:

```sql
SELECT product_id, warehouse_id, quantity_on_hand FROM inventories WHERE product_id = &product_id;
```

But I think '&' does not work here as it is giving me an error: ERROR 1064 (You have an error in your SQL syntax.

And I couldn't find any other method for it. Please suggest how to do it.

Comment: What language and library are you using to do the query?  Show your code

Comment: I'm using MySQL command line client and code is same as I wrote above.

Comment: Is this in some kind of script?

Comment: No, it's just an individual query. I'm just trying to learn sql using MySQL command line.

Comment: 'user to input the 'product_id'' - if you mean interactively (from a prompt) using something like an INPUT command then no mysql has no such feature.

Comment: What shell and OS are you using?

Comment: @ysth i'm using MySQL on Windows 10

Comment: @P.Salmon yes exactly, I want to prompt the user for input. So, just to clarify, how exactly can we do this? Can we use java for this task?

Comment: 'Exactly'? - dunno you asked a specific question but not explained what you are trying to achieve.  But to clarify RDBMS allow you define entities(tables) ,define relationships between them (DDL) and manipulate data in them (DML). They don't have any nice reporting features (there are many out there which use RDBMS as backends) or any nice user interactivity (you have to build it using stuff like the wamp stack and possibly java(I can't say I'm not a java user))

Comment: Actually I studied this site and it tells that SQL Developer and SQL * Plus 
supports the ampersand substitution variable  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql_certificate/restricting_and_sorting_data.htm

Comment: And so I researched whether we can use this substitution variable in MySQL as well but it does not support it.

Comment: in a programming language (which the mysql client is distinctly not) you would use a placeholder, e.g. `select * from foo where bar=?` and then specify a value where your codes executes the query

Answer (score 0):

MySQL use @ instead of & to make substitutional variable

Comment: Tried it but it is not prompting the user for the input

Comment: Here is the good ref about how to use the @ not the exact same way as in oracle https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38651655/mysql-procedure-to-accept-user-input-and-to-show-same-as-result-not-working

Comment: you would use this like by doing (at the mysql client prompt) `set @foo="abc"` then `select * from bar where baz=@foo`